# How handle UpdateException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, updateexception

I need handle exception duplicate.

```
var resource = new Resource() { url = tbUrl.Text };
try
{
    context.Resource.AddObject(resource);
    context.SaveChanges();
}   
catch(UpdateException ex)
{
    // how to know exactly which is why the error occurred
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw;
}
```

UPDATE:

I need to catch an error that occurs when I try to not add **unique value**.
UpdateException - is triggered when an error in adding data.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out whether `resource` is already added to `context.Resource`? Otherwise, I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be a little late, but for anyone with an ASP.NET database update error looking for details,  the InnerException error handler is extraordinary helpful and detailed.

```
        try { 

            db.SaveChanges();                              
        }

        catch (System.Data.UpdateException ex)    
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }


        catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException ex) //DbContext
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            throw;
        }
```

The T-SQL in the database prevents the insertion of duplicate cities.

```
USE [ModelFirstApplication]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [UQ_Address_City]    Script Date: 5/30/2012 7:26:16 AM ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UQ_Address_City] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
([City] ASC)
GO
```

So, if the user tries inserting "Spokane" a second time into the Addresses table into this demo application, the above exception handler reports

```
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. 

See the inner exception for details. ---> 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_Address_City'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Addresses'. 
The duplicate key value is (Spokane).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Knowing which exception handler to use is pretty darned handy and your question is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

See [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).
Also, for WPF application is make sense to look at the [Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

the best practice is to write the exception message and stack trace to log file and get the data by reading the log file i reccomand using log4net http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/